# How to add and listen to click event in embedded html in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, event-handling

I am working with embedded html which comes from the server. I have added an aditional element in it. I also added click method but it is not working I would like to know how can I fix it. My code is given below:

```
async ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.unlockOrientation();   
        const state = history.state;

        await this.userService.checkForCrucialData();

        if (state && state.workout) {

            this.workout = state.workout;
            this.featuredImage = this.workout._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url;
            this.workoutTitle = this.workout.title.rendered;
            this.workoutBody = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.correctFileData(this.workout.content.rendered));
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
            this.localReferrer = state.referrer;

            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('FOUND', this.playerContainers);
                console.log('FOUND2', this.playerContainer);
                console.log('FOUND3', this.workoutBodyEl);
                const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
                this.vimeoPlayers = [];
                console.log('FOUND4', iframes);
                iframes.forEach((iframe) => {
                    iframe.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');
                    iframe.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
                    // this.vimeoPlayers.push(new Player(iframe));
                });
                console.log(this.vimeoPlayers);
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
correctFileData(response:string) :string {
        let el = document.createElement('html');
        el.innerHTML = response;
        var instructions = el.getElementsByClassName('col-12-instructions');
        for ( var i =0; i<instructions.length ; i++) {
            instructions[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div class = "instructions-container" (click)="toggleInstructions()" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;margin: 6px 0 0 0 "><h3 class="heading" style="padding: 10px 10px 30px 0; margin: 0">TIPS</h3><img   src="../../../assets/imgs/mbm_chevron2.png" style="height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;margin: 6px 0 0 0 "></div>')
        }

        var instructionsC = el.getElementsByClassName('instructions-container');
        for ( var i =0; i<instructionsC.length ; i++) {
            instructionsC[i].addEventListener('click',  this.toggleInstructions.bind(this))
        }
               

        // !this.showInstructions && instructions.remove()
        return el.outerHTML;
    }

    toggleInstructions(){
        this.showInstructions = !this.showInstructions;
        this.workoutBody = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.correctFileData(this.workout.content.rendered));

        console.log('this.showInstructions', this.showInstructions);
    }
```

Template code:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar >
      <ion-title></ion-title>

       <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button text=""></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>

  <ion-button  class="ion-padding-end no-padding" routerLink="/profile-home" routerDirection="back" slot="end" >
    <ion-icon  name="close" color="light" ></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen="true" class="gradient card-background-page">
    <div class="header-container ion-padding-top bgimg-top" *ngIf="featuredImage"
            [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74)),url(' + featuredImage + ')', 'background-size': 'cover'}">
            <ion-button fill="clear" color="white" class="back-arrow bring-to-front" (click)="goBack()"></ion-button>

            <div class="lesson-title">
                <h1 class="text-primary text-white" [innerHTML]="workoutTitle"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div *ngIf="workout">


        <div class="content-container" class="ion-padding">
            <div class="workout-text-container">
                <!-- div class="lead-text" style="font-size: 1rem; padding-top: 20px">Follow exercises in order below.<br/>Tap 'Workout Complete' to log the session.<br/><br/></div -->
        <div class = "tip-container" (click)="toggleTips()" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;margin: 6px 0 0 0 " *ngIf="localReferrer === 'gym'">
            <h3 class="heading" style="padding: 10px 10px 30px 0; margin: 0">TIPS</h3>
            <img   src="../../../assets/imgs/mbm_chevron2.png" style="height: 1.5rem; width: 1.5rem;margin: 6px 0 0 0 " [ngClass] = "{'pointing-up-icon': showTips}"></div>
        <div style="font-size: .8rem" *ngIf="localReferrer === 'gym' && showTips === true">
         'Reps' - Number of complete movements<br/>
   'Sets' - A set of reps<br/>
   'Rep Max' - Max weight for that many reps<br/>
   'Rest' - Rest time between sets</div>


        <!-- div style="font-size: .8rem" *ngIf="localReferrer === 'home'">
         'Reps' - Number of complete movements<br/>
   'Rest' - Rest time between sets</div -->
            <div #workoutBodyEl [innerHTML]="workoutBody" class="workout-body">
                    
            </div>

           
            </div>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button class="primary" (click)="toggleInstructions()" expand="block" fill="outline"
                        color="tertiary">SHOW INSTRUCTIONS</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-button class="primary" (click)="uploadTrainingData()" expand="block" fill="outline"
                        color="tertiary">WORKOUT COMPLETE</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I have added the code of the template so it will be clear what is happening. Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your component template and reset of your code. From the first look it seems that you are trying to use the javascript way of event listening and rendering a custom html in an angular component, which angular does not recommend. Let's have a look first at the whole code you have.

Comment: @MehyarSawas I have updated my question detail